# django sum values for loop in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have this template that is a search engine.
I need all the matched items to be added, but as I did, it sums up all the database items.

I need to sum all the items' prices after applying the filter.
In other words, I need to sum all the loop items:
 {{images.price | mul:images.pictures}}

views.py

```
    def search(request):
        sales_list = Images.objects.all() 
        sales_filter = ImagesFilter(request.GET, queryset=sales_list)
        places_count = sales_filter.qs.annotate(total=Sum('pictures'))
        return render(request, 'paneladmin/sales_list.html', {'filter': sales_filter, 'places_count': places_count})
```

filter.py

```
    class ImagesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        checkin = django_filters.NumberFilter(widget=DatePickerInput(format='%d'),field_name='checkin', lookup_expr='day'  )
        checkin1 = django_filters.NumberFilter(widget=DatePickerInput(format='%m'),field_name='checkin', lookup_expr='month'  )
        checkin2 = django_filters.NumberFilter(widget=DatePickerInput(format='%Y'),field_name='checkin', lookup_expr='year'  )
        # usando o name__photographers eu estou dizendo que quero busca o name da tabela photographes, desse modo terei um boxlistt em meu template
        name__photographers =  django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', field_name='name')

        class Meta:
            model = Images
            fields = ['name', 'checkin']
```

sales_list.html

```
    {% load mathfilters %}
    {% for images in filter.qs %}
    {{images.price | mul:images.pictures}}
    {{places_count.total }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

with the help of friends here at stackoverflow I got
solve.
It is now working perfectly.
Thank you all

views.py

```
    def search(request):
        sales_list = Images.objects.all() 
        sales_filter = ImagesFilter(request.GET, queryset=sales_list)
        places_count = sales_filter.qs.aggregate(total_amount=Sum('pictures'))
        return render(request, 'paneladmin/sales_list.html', {
        'filter': sales_filter, 'places_count': places_count
        })
```

sales_list.html

```
   {% load mathfilters %}
   {% for images in filter.qs %}
   {{places_count.total_amount | mul:images.price }}
```